# using CoreLocation and CLGeocoder to get "city, country"

Tags: ios, swift, core-location, clgeocoder

I'm using `CoreLocation` and `CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(location)` to get the formatted location of the user. I want to display it through the format "city, country".

```
CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(location) { (placemark, error) in
    if error != nil {
        print(error)
        return
    } else {
        if let place = placemark?[0] {


            if let administrationArea = place.administrativeArea, let city = place.locality, let country = place.country {
                print("\(administrationArea) \(city), \(country)")
                manager.stopUpdatingLocation()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code works but for some test I get:

```
CA   Cupertino, United States
Tokyo   Shinjuku, Japan
Île-de-France   Paris, France
```

It works for Cupertino and Paris but, Tokyo, splitted in wards, don't fit to this method.

I have tried to check addressDictionary but it's depreciated.

Comment: Nice [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39956825/swift-3-reversegeocodelocation-does-not-its-completion-handler) is available here.

Comment: As I understand, you want "Tokio" to be the city. It might be just misleading: Tokio in fact is the administrative center of the city of Sinjuku.

Comment: @AndreasOetjen hmm I see so the result is good but not what I expected. Do you know if this is only the case for Tokio ? Or there might be other cities

Comment: @Florian_L I think it's highly likely that there will be more cases, although I'm not aware of samples. Just think of "New York", which is the state, while the city is named "New York City" (although I'm not sure what the geocoder will do in this sample)

Comment: No the geocoder is fine with NY and all the cities I have tested for now. I only have this case for Tokyo for now. Thank you for your help